# How to update UITabbar badgevalue after getting data in array?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I have two view controllers. In one view controller I am getting the data in an `NSMutableArray`.
I want to update another(second) tab bar controller's badge value when I am in my first view controller.

Please tell me how to do this.

I have tried using `NSNotification` but not succeed.

Comment: Both Viewcontroller is in tabbar?

Comment: yup. there are two viewcontrollers for two seperate tabbar..

Comment: K check my code and tell me if you get it or got error.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your ViewController, Where you want to set badge, is at 2 place than Place this code when your array get value.

Place this code in you first viewController

```
UIViewController * vc1 = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[vc1.tabBarItem setBadgeValue: @"Dilip"];
```

Comment: Please use 1 in objectAtIndex because starting of any array will be from 0.

Comment: Dilip Still not Displaying :(

Comment: ViewController Which contain array is in tabbar?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
NSMutableArray *sourceArray = @"Your value--------"; 
    int indexICareAbout = 2;
            NSString *badgeValue = [sourceArray objectAtIndex:2];

            [[[[[self tabBarController] viewControllers]
            objectAtIndex: indexICareAbout] tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:badgeValue];
```

Comment: i'av try this but Not Working :(